EAS Update: Is it possible to use EAS Update with Reactnative cli project that is distributed with cli?
I have few concerns about EAS updated If anyone is well versed and have enough knowledge of EAS update.

Is it possible that we can use EAS update with app that is already on the app stores? or is it necessary to used build ->. submit -> update
If yes to the above answer than can you please let know the steps you follow for app already in stores and created with react-native-cli/create-native-init

I tried reading docs but docs keep moving me from here and there as they seem so scattered.
